# Is there a CSS selector to detect if an input has a text file selected?

Tags: css, css-selectors

I'm trying to have some file inputs, and have them only show up if the previous one has been filled. This can use css 3 as well.

Answer (score 8):

An example worth thousands words: [Display X input, one at a time](http://jsfiddle.net/J8evD/)

The idea is simple, if an input set as required is empty, it's invalid. From there, all you have to do is set all input as required and use the :invalid pseudo class. Should work great with label too.

```css
input:invalid~input:invalid {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<input type="file" required>
<input type="file" required>
<input type="file" required>
```

Comment: the downside of this is that you need to fill all the inputs, making it unviable, it's not really dynamic, as far as I researched this can't be completely achieved without JS

Comment: Adding novalidate to the form tag allow to send the form with empty input. Not sure if it is worthwhile. Dynamic number of input will not be achievable without JS anyway.

Answer (score 6):

To expand on Yi Jiang's comment, selectors against the "value" attribute won't notice changes to the "value" property. The "value" attribute is bound to the ["defaultValue" property](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-HTML/html.html#ID-26091157), while the ["value" property](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-HTML/html.html#ID-49531485) isn't bound to any attribute (thanks to porneL for pointing this out).

Note there's a similar relationship with the "[checked](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/interact/forms.html#adef-checked)" attribute and "[defaultChecked](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-HTML/html.html#ID-20509171)" and "[checked](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-HTML/html.html#ID-30233917)" properties; if you use an attribute selector `[checked]` rather than the pseudo-class `:checked`, you won't see style change when a checkbox's state changes. Unlike the "checked" family, "value" doesn't have a corresponding pseudo-class that you could use.

Try the following test page:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Dynamic attribute selectors</title>
    <style type="text/css">
     input:not([value]), div:not([value]) {
       background-color: #F88;
     }

     input[value], div[value] {
       border: 5px solid #8F8;
     }
     input[value=""], div[value=""] {
       border: 5px solid #F8F;
     }

     input:not([value=""]), div:not([value=""]) {
       color: blue;
       border-style: dashed;
     }

     *.big {
         font-size: 200%;
     }
    </style>
    <script>
      function getElt() {
          var id=prompt("Enter ID of element", "d1");
          if (id) {
              return document.getElementById(id);
          } else {
              return {className: ''};
          }
      }

      function embiggen() {
          getElt().className="big";
          return false;
      }

      function smallify() {
          getElt().className="";
          return false;
      }
    </script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <form method="post"  enctype="multipart/form-data"> 
      <div id="d1">no value</div>
      <div id="d2" value="">empty value</div>
      <div id="d3" value="some">some value</div>
      <p><label for="foo">foo:</label> <input name="foo" id="foo" /></p> 
      <p><label for="bam">bam:</label> <input name="bam" id="bam" value="bug-AWWK" /></p> 
      <p><label for="file">File to upload:</label> <input type="file" name="file" id="file" onchange="setValueAttr(this)"/></p>
      <input type="button" value="Embiggen" onclick="return embiggen()" />
      <input type="button" value="Smallify" onclick="return smallify()" />
    </body>
</html>
```

Changing the value of anything and the style won't change. Change the class of anything and the style will change. If you add the following JS function and bind it to a change event on an input, the background style will change.

```
      function bindValue(elt) {
          var oldVal=elt.getAttribute('value');
          elt.setAttribute('value', elt.value);
          var newVal=elt.getAttribute('value');
          if (oldVal != newVal) {
              alert('Had to change value from "'+oldVal+'" to "'+newVal+'"');
          }
      }
```

This binds the "value" property to the "value" attribute, so updates to the former by user input will propagate to the latter (programmatically setting the "value" property won't cause a change event).

In examining the JS properties of file inputs before and after (by use of the following script), the only one with an appreciable change was "value". From this, I doubt there are any other HTML attributes that change and could hence be used in an attribute selector.

```
<script>
  var file = {blank: {}, diff: {}};
  var fInput = document.getElementById('file');
  for (p in fInput) {
    try {
      file.blank[p] = fInput[p];
    } catch (err) {
      file.blank[p] = "Error: setting '"+p+"' resulted in '"+err+"'";          
    }
  }

  function fileDiff() {
    for (p in fInput) {
      try {
        if (file.blank[p] != fInput[p]) {
          file.diff[p] = {orig: file.blank[p], now: fInput[p]};
        }
      } catch (err) {
        //file.diff[p] = "Error: accessing '"+p+"' resulted in '"+err+"'";          
      }
    }

  }

  if (fInput.addEventListener) {
    fInput.addEventListener('change', fileDiff, false);
  } else if (fInput.attachEvent) {
    fInput.attachEvent('onchange', fileDiff);
  } else {
    fInput.onchange = fileDiff;
  }
</script>
```

You can hack together something using a link to a non-existent fragment and the `:visited` pseudo class, but it's quite egregious.

```
<style>
 a input {
   display: none;
 }
 :not(a) + a input,
 a:visited + a input
 {
   display: block /* or "inline" */ ;
 }

</style>
...
<a href="#asuhacrpbt"><input type="file" ... /></a>
<a href="#cmupbnhhpw"><input type="file" ... /></a>
<a href="#mcltahcrlh"><input type="file" ... /></a>
```

You'd need to generate unvisited targets for the links every time the page is loaded. Since you'd have to do it server side, you couldn't do this with complete certainty, though you could get the probability of generating a previously visited target arbitrarily close to 0. It also doesn't work on all browsers, such as Safari. I suspect this is due to the following from [CSS2](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#link-pseudo-classes) and [CSS3](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#the-link-pseudo-classes-link-and-visited):

> Note: It is possible for style sheet authors to abuse the :link and :visited pseudo-classes to determine which sites a user has visited without the user's consent.
>
> UAs may therefore treat all links as unvisited links, or implement other measures to preserve the user's privacy while rendering visited and unvisited links differently.

You might be able to hack something together using other selectors on other elements, but I suspect this can't be done cleanly.

Comment: To clarify: selectors matching `value` attribute *are* always re-evaluated dynamically whenever `value` *attribute* changes, and it works in all browsers supporting CSS2 selectors. CSS makes no exception here. The confusing part is that `value` *attribute* is **not updated** in response to `<input>` changes. `value` *attribute* maps to `defaultValue` DOM *property*, and `value` *property* has no corresponding DOM *attribute*. JS and HTML/CSS are two different worlds.

Comment: Well, it works if the `defaultValue` gets updated via JavaScript (jQuery for simplification): `jQuery( 'input[type=file]' ).change( function( e ) { this.defaultValue = this.value; } );`

Comment: @feeela that's great! Any known downsides?

Answer (score 0):

To select empty fields you can try

```
input[type=file][value=""] {
    background-color: red;
}
```

I tested it on jsfiddle.  There at least, I needed to define an empty value attribute on the input tag for it to work

```
<input type="file" id="test" value="">
```

Using the '+' operator as you've done in your example would match two separate file inputs, one right after the other.  It doesn't examine two attributes of the same tag as you appear to want.

Comment: What I want is to only show 1 input at first, then once that one has had a file selected, show the second one, and so on. I tested you suggestion and it doesn't change once the file is selected. It only looks at the initial value of the "value" attribute and does nothing when it changes.

Comment: @manixrock CSS can't be used like this - the selectors are only evaluated once when the page is loaded, and that's it. You'll need Javascript for this

Comment: @Yi Jiang - That's not quite true: `input { margin-left:10px; } input:checked { margin-left:20px; }`; add a checkbox input, and when you check it it will move to the right; uncheck it and it will move to the left; this proves css is evaluated at runtime on the page, not just while loading. I'm looking for something like this, but adapted for file inputs.

Comment: @Yi Jiang: selectors are evaluated whenever DOM changes. However, `value` DOM attribute only contains default value, and not current value (which is a DOM *property* not visible to CSS).

Comment: @porneL Yes, you're right. I should have clarified what I meant when I said that. But my point still stands - you can't do with with CSS alone.