# CSS selector for empty file input

Tags: html, css, css-selectors, forms

I know that styling file input is pretty minimal, which is not a bad thing.

Is there some way of selecting file input which is empty?

The plan is to show or hide a submit button depending on whether the file input is empty.

Comment: Without help of JavaScript `element.files` you can't

Comment: You should use Javascript for something like this.

Comment: Yes I mistakenly deleted the "there" in the 2nd line. But there should be no need to preface your question to prevent anyone saying you can't input style elements - it is common knowledge they can be styled so if anyone had that little knowledge they shouldn't be answering at all and can be ignored :)

Comment: @MoisheLipsker Yes and no — I can’t get it to work for me, so no, but if it worked, then yes.

Comment: I'm pretty confused by the multiple people saying you can't do this with CSS and then see the accepted answer is a pure CSS solution ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: @Edmund Reed: The accepted answer was chosen because the specific use case means that the file input can simply be marked as required, since the entire point is to disallow form submission unless a file is chosen. But the answer to the general question remains that it is indeed impossible to match an empty file input with CSS if the field is optional.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

If you are comfortable marking the `input` as `required`, [you could do it with just css](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12081682/4297364):

```css
input:invalid ~ .chosen {
    display: none;
}
input:valid ~ .empty {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<input type="file" required><br>

<span class="empty">Empty</span>
<span class="chosen">Chosen</span>
```

Comment: That’s a pretty good approach. The whole point is that the file is required before you submit, which is why I want to hide it otherwise. Thanks

Comment: Brill-yantz. Love the touch on `required`.

Answer (score 2):

> Is there some way of selecting file input which is empty?

No.

You'll need JavaScript. You can find several answers here on SO and elsewhere. The basic idea is to watch the element for `change` events, add a class such as `non-empty` indicating there are files selected, then style  `input[type="file"].non-empty + label`, assuming you are using the technique of using a `label` as the replacement file input button. You will have to special-case `form.reset()` which empties file inputs inside the form but does not trigger a `change` event on the input. Here's some sample code (without the `form.reset` part):

```js
// Add a class to a file input if it's not empty.
function mark() { this.classList.toggle('non-empty', this.files.length); }

// Watch a file input and update non-empty status.
function watch(input) { input.addEventListener('change', mark); }

// Get all file inputs.
const inputs = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('input[type=file]'));

// Watch all file inputs in the whole document.
inputs . forEach(watch);
```

```css
input[type="file"]                          { width: 0.1px; height: 0.1px; }
input[type="file"].non-empty + label        { color: green; }
input[type="file"].non-empty + label::after { content: ' (specified)'; }
```

```html
<input type="file" id="input">
<label for="input">Specify file</label>
```

Comment: The 0.1px dimensions intrigue me. Are there any browsers that have trouble submitting file inputs with display: none?

Comment: @BoltClock Apparently, yes, at least according to something I saw somewhere once.